# onActivityCreated launched three times

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to start new activity when a value ("Status") change in my Database Firebase.
But i have problem because onActivityCreated is launched three times (because my onDataChange of my Listener is called several times). How can i fix this ? Thank you in advance.

```
//LISTEN IF THE GAME START ::
        mStart = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms").child(roomId).child("Proprieties").child("Status");
        mStart.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("GAME")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(WaitGameActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

And Log :

```
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: onActivityCreated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the value listener once you receive an event like below:

```
 mStart.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
                mStart.removeValueEventListener(this); //remove once you get the event
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("GAME")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(WaitGameActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

onDataChange is called multiple times in case you have not removed the listener properly and are creating a new instance of your listener in your activity every time you open it.

Call this once you recieved data:
`mStart.removeValueEventListener(this)`